# Datamax not printing when networked

Tags: networking, network-printer

I've run into a weird issue. I had to set up 4 [Datamax printers](https://www.honeywellaidc.com/products/printers/industrial/i-class-mark-ii) for work, and 3 of them gave me no issue. However, the 4th one won't print when connected to the network, not even test labels from the printer itself. If I print a test label from the printer after it turns on, but before it grabs an IP address, it comes out fine, but as soon as it gets an IP that stops working. I created the printer on our print server, and when trying to send a test page from there, it just gets stuck in the print queue. Also worth noting, there is a symbol on the printer screen that indicates it is connected to the network. And I am able to use the printer's web interface [pictured here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKGo2.png)

I'm not really sure what's going on. The switch port it is connected to is configured just like the rest, and the driver on the print server is the same as the rest. Any ideas what could be causing this?

Comment: Are you able to PING the printer when it shows connected to network? Any network errors on the print server?

Comment: @DaveM yes, I am able to ping the IP and it returns with no errors or dropped packets. No errors on the print server either.

Answer (score 1):

I forgot my login, but I'm OP, and I ran into this very issue today. Funny enough, the top result of me googling the problem is this page. But, I FIGURED IT OUT!

There were (paper) print jobs sent directly to the IP address of the printer. I was able to resolve it by assigning a paper printer the IP address and letting it spit out all of the print jobs.